# Dryer won't heat even after replacing the Thermal Fuse, Thermal Cutoff Fuse, Thermostat Cutoff Kit, Heating Element, Thermistor, high-limit thermostat

Tags: electrical, repair, thermostat, heating, dryer

Dryer won't heat. Heating element wont hold continuity. Ordered a New one, got the wrong part, took the coils off the new heating element and put them on old.. installed.. this worked well for 5 min then it started lightly smoking and tripped the breaker. Ordered new and correct part, it came in a kit. Checked and flipped the breaker. Removed all lint from dryer, hose and wall. I've replaced the Thermal Fuse, Thermal Cutoff Fuse, Thermostat Cutoff Kit, Heating Element, Thermistor, high-limit thermostat, these are all the parts that came with the replacement heating element, probably said somethings twice there. Checked all the new parts I replaced for continuity. Everything was good. Checked the power cord, and connections, still good. Fan blows, barrel spins but no heat. I checked for heat in all settings. I can't find any burned wires. Not sure what to check next.

Comment: heat needs 240 Volt, that is a dual circuit breaker (two connected together)

Comment: did you check voltages?

Comment: What does "Heating element wont hold continuity" mean in terms of the actual measurement's you've taken?

Comment: Some Formatting would Make this More readable As would The removal Of all The random Caps and The use Of complete Sentences maybe Even tell Us what Brand and Model of Dryer you Have.

Comment: Roasting a new element sounds like a power supply problem. Has something changed in that regard?

Comment: The second heating element hasn't burned up but it also won't heat up at all.

Comment: I replaced the heating element with a new one that works. I'll have to check the readings on everything when I get home. I did reset the breaker but I didn't check the output. The dryer will turn on, the drum spins and the fan blows, just no heat. This is an electric whirlpool duet dryer, model # gew9250pw0. Thank you all for your help.

Comment: Even though the parts came with the replacement element, you are still just throwing parts at, hoping it fixes it. That the incorrect replacement started smoking and tripped a breaker is REALLY REALLY BAD. You hacked the incorrect replacement part into the old one.  Probably wrong wattage element.  You may have fried a relay in doing so. You need to correctly diagnose it by checking voltages according to the wiring diagram. I'd start by checking at the element, if zero, work upstream until you find the problem.

Comment: By the 2nd heating element, I mean the 2nd one I've purchased to replace the 1st one that failed.

Comment: This is a problem that I had with a previous dryer - I had a tied-together double breaker servicing the dryer, and one half had tripped without triggering the other.  In effect, I had one half of the service going to the dryer.  It happened to be the case that the dryer used the still-live pole for control elements, fan, etc.  Try re-tripping the breaker(s), and also checking voltage at the input to make sure it's getting the right power in.